# Take the containing string array after split in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have some text like:

```
 text= "  First sentence. Second sentence. Third sentence."
```

And after this I split by '.':

```
 new_split = text.split('.')
```

I will receive: `['First sentence', Second sentence','Third sentence']`

How could I print entire second sentence if I call it?

Like:

```
if 'second' in new_split : print (new_split[GET SECOND SENTENCE])
```

I would like to know how to get entire 'second sentence' if I know in my split there exists a sentence that contains my keyword.

Comment: You were not aware of basic list indexing before asking this question?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  As I understand it, O.P is aware of list indexing, but not aware of `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
text= "  First sentence. Second sentence. Third sentence."
new_text = [i for i in text.split('.') if "second" in i.lower()][0]
```

Output:

```
' Second sentence'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text= "  First sentence. Second sentence. Third sentence."

[print(i) for i in text.split('.') if "second" in i.lower()]
```

which `prints`:

```
 Second sentence
```

---

Above is the shortest way I could think of doing it in terms of `lines`, but you just as easily do it with a `for-loop` rather than a `list-comp`:

```
for sentence in text.split('.'):
    if "second" in sentence.lower():
        print(sentence)
```

Comment: note that it yields `"  Second sentence"`, unlike OP said.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre My bad, I should read more carefully, I will update the answer

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yea sorry about that, I have updated the answer to answer the question properly now...

Answer (score 2):

To find the index of the first sentence in a list of sentences which is containing a given substring:

```
i = next(i for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences) if word in sentence)
```

The same thing with simple Python:

```
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    if word in sentence:
        break
else:
    # the word is not in any of the sentences
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if new_split[1] != '': 
    print(new_split[1])
```